# Two "Routers" and a NAS

Tags: networking, router, nas, gateway, synology

I have what Xfinity calls a gateway (really a modem/router combo) on the main floor of my home.  I have an ethernet cable coming from it, connecting to a powerline networking device at the wall.  I then have a powerline networking adapter in my basement (where my office is) that brings Internet to my actual router, which I have my NAS and such connected to.  However, my NAS is complaining about there being two routers.  Unless I am mistaken, I believe I can't set the Xfinity to bridge since I use it to carry Internet to the powerline adapter.  So, what should I do?  Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Your question and problem is unclear, but why dont you change your "actual router" into an access point by connecting the gateway to the LAN port and disabling DHCP?

Comment: The powerline adapter itself is nothing more than a bridge; what does it need internet access for?